# Why don't my arrays outside of the function retain any values?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to create a program that reads in text from a file and searches for certain words, then I process from there. I'm using arrays to store the data that I want however when I try to access the array outside of the function only the first spot in the array is occupied, and it is with the last value read by the function. Of course the code is incomplete but I need to know, what's causing this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl; using std::string; 
using std::ifstream; using std::getline;

string data, strL = "language", strC = "created", strT = "timestamp";
string lang[2], date[2];
int count = 0, l = 0, c = 0;
ifstream rawData("testsample.txt");

void search(int count, string data, string heading) {
int x, y;
if (data.find(heading) != string::npos) {
    //cout << heading << endl;
    if (heading == strL) {
        x = 4; y = 2;
        lang[count] = data.substr(data.find(strL) + strL.length() + x, y);
        //cout << lang[count] << endl;
    }
    if (heading == strC) {
        x = 4; y = 29;
        date[count] = data.substr(data.find(strC) + strC.length() + x, y);
    }
}
count++;
}

int main() {
while (getline(rawData, data)) {
    search(l, data, strL);
    search(c, data, strC);
    //count++;
}cout << lang[0] << " " << lang[1] << endl;
cout << date[1];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shown code is unparsable chaos. Global variables. Bizarre, illogical  indentation, that randomly disappears, in places. Magic constants. Whatever it's trying to do, it can't be right, and there's no way to make it right short of scrapping the whole thing, and starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you have global variable `count`, and also a parameter to the `search` function `count`. The `count++` statement within the `search` function increments the parameter, not the global. Since there is no loop in this function, the index you are assigning to `lang` and `date` is always zero.

Removing the parameter may cause the code to do what you want, although, if you process more than two of each, you'll overflow. You might consider using `std::vector` or other dynamically sizing container class.